# Linq Sql Int null equal to null. Not returning rows

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a linq query with a where clause as below

```
var ExistingGroupDataSource = (from ppatg in dbContext.XXXXXXXXX
                               join pd1 in dbContext.XXXXXXXXXXX on ppatg.ScheduleID equals pd1.ScheduleID 
                               where  pd1.GroupID == null
                               select
                               new 
                               {
                                FinishPDI = pd1.ProductionDateID,
                                FinishingDate = pd1.WorkFlowDate,
                                ppatg.GroupName,
                                ppatg.PNTGroupID
                               });
```

In the database GroupID is an int that can be null. The linq query returns rows without the filtered where clause but none when I include the where clause. There are null values in the GroupId column in the database.

It is definitely this statement that produces no results. All the literature on the subject online says that this is equivalent to

```
pd1.GroupID is null // in sql
```

I am getting results that contradict this

Sql code is

```
 select pd1.ProductionDateID as FinishPDI, pd1.WorkflowDate as FinishingDate,GroupName ,PNTGroupId 
 from XXXXXXXXXXXX 
 inner join XXXXXXXXXXXX pd1 on 
 XXXXXXXXXXXX.ScheduleId = pd1.ScheduleID
 where pd1.GroupID is null
```

Comment: Is GroupID in your Model a nullable type?

Comment: Yes, in the model GroupID is a int?

Comment: It should be int? GroupID.

Comment: Can you show sql code?

Comment: @Backs added sql code

Comment: And executing sql code directly returns correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine your `where` with the `join`, which should give you the expected results:

```
var ExistingGroupDataSource = (from ppatg in dbContext.XXXXXXXXX
                               join pd1 in dbContext.XXXXXXXXXXX.Where(p => !p.GroupId.HasValue) on ppatg.ScheduleID equals pd1.ScheduleID 
                               select
                               new 
                               {
                                FinishPDI = pd1.ProductionDateID,
                                FinishingDate = pd1.WorkFlowDate,
                                ppatg.GroupName,
                                ppatg.PNTGroupID
                               });
```